Find the latest date in excel out of the two columns

I need to find the latest date out of the two columns. If the "revised end date" column has a date, than that is the latest date. The "revised end date" could have improved date than "planned end date" or a later date as well. Explained well in the appended image. I need the "date as an output" and not the time. Thanks for your help and guidance.
The rows belong to a particular item and hence they are the ones that need to be compared.
Tried =INT(MAX([@[Planned End Date]],[@[Revised End Date]])) but couldn't find success.

You should show us the whole data - as you say "The rows belong to a particular item" ... and furthermore: you mean "If there is any revised End Date" than take the max value from there"?

MAX() should work.

Probably something like =INT(IF(C3="";B3;C3)) should work. Then just  apply format date to cell and drag down

Use IF() to check dates in column C. Try-
=IF(ISNUMBER(C363),C363,B363)


As per OP request "I need the "date as an output" and not the time.": =IF(ISNUMBER(C363),TEXT(C363,"dd-mm-yyyy"),TEXT(B363,"dd-mm-yyyy"))

@Excellor TEXT(C363,"dd-mm-yyyy")" is not the "date as an output". It's the text. The date as output can be reached using formatting or INT function like =INT(IF(ISNUMBER(C363),C363,B363)).

@rotabor I can still do calculations on TEXT() outputs formatted as date. INT gives me a number (although with formatting it can be changed into a date format).

@Excellor TEXT converts the argument to a text. It's the undesired operation without a reason. Format cells to display the date only (dd-mm-yyyy). Additionally, INT can cut the time of the day to the midnight which can be the best in some cases.

Many thanks to all for your answers and support. MAX() will not work as I may have the max date in the planned column and the revised planned date could be a better or improvised date (earlier date). If there is a date in revised planned date, I need the latest commit from that column.
